# NRWL NX - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')

Tags: javascript, angular, nrwl, nx-workspace

I have nx 14.4.3 version in my system. And when I run nx serve it gives me the error :- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')

Somewhere I saw answer to the question asking me to downgrade nx version to 10.4.15. But that doesn't work either. I tried nx migrate @nrwl/workspace@10.4.15. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling with npm install nx@10.4.15. No success.

Please let me know where am I going wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your full stack trace and package.json otherwise this is just guess work.

Comment: @coloraddict, did you ever resolve this?